NaN returned in R when all values are numeric
I'm working with a data frame with multiple variables, and I've been creating correlation matrices with no problem. I just created a new variable, which is the ratio of two other variables, and tried to run correlations between that new variable and others. R returns "NaN" (Not A Number). All relevant variables are numeric, is.nan(NEW VARIABLE) returned all FALSE, and I tried to limit the decimal places of my new variable, thinking there were too many. That did nothing. Here's my relevant code:
S1901Income_2022_crimetest <- S1901Income2022 |>
  select(HouseholdsTotal , Pct0to10k , Pct10kto14999 , Pct15kto24999...8 , Pct25kto34999 , Pct35kto49999 , Pct50kto74999 , Pct75kto99999 , Pct100kto149999 , Pct150kto199999 , Pct200korMore...22 , HouseholdMedianIncome)

ratiohighlow <- (S1901Income_2022_crimetest$Pct200korMore...22 / S1901Income_2022_crimetest$Pct0to10k)
ratiohighlow <- round(ratiohighlow , digits = 8)

Crime2022_S1901Income <- Crime2022 |>
  select(-FIPS, -year)

IncomeandCrime2022 <- cbind(Crime2022_S1901Income , S1901Income_2022_crimetest , ratiohighlow)

cor(IncomeandCrime2022$TotIncidents , ratiohighlow)

In this code, "ratiohighlow" is the new, problematic variable. I've been running correlations between "TotIncidents" and other variables without issue. Here is a sample of my output, as requested:
# A tibble: 10 × 12
   HouseholdsTotal Pct0to10k Pct10kto14999 Pct15kto24999...8 Pct25kto34999 Pct35kto49999 Pct50kto74999
             <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1          265794       6.6           5                 8.6           8.4          11.9          16.7
 2         1665560       4.2           2.5               5.5           6.6          10.6          17.1
 3          151490       4.4           2.2               6             7.2          11.4          20.2
 4           74678       6.9           4.5               9.3           9.8          14.1          20.2
 5            6559       6.2           7.4              13.1           7.2           7.9          22.4
 6            7194       9             8                16             7.8          13.3          18.6
 7           19021       5.3           3.6              14.7          12.8          16.8          20.2
 8          104164       2.9           2.2               5.3           6            10.2          17.3
 9           15172       5.7           5                10.9          10.8          15.1          20.6
10            3587       8.8          10.2              15             8.7          13.6          17.9
# ℹ 5 more variables: Pct75kto99999 <dbl>, Pct100kto149999 <dbl>, Pct150kto199999 <dbl>, Pct200korMore...22 <dbl>,
#   HouseholdMedianIncome <dbl>

Pct100kto149999
<dbl>
Pct150kto199999
<dbl>
Pct200korMore...22
<dbl>
HouseholdMedianIncome
<dbl>
ratiohighlow
<dbl>
14.1    7.3 9.3 63595   1.4090909
18.6    9.5 11.3    80675   2.6904762
19.4    7.6 6.3 73313   1.4318182
13.3    4.8 4.1 56439   0.5942029
14.0    5.0 2.6 58695   0.4193548
12.0    2.4 2.2 44804   0.2444444


You'll have to provide (a sample of) your data, preferably using dput().

I can't tell from the data you provided, but my guess is that you have Inf in the ratiohighlow vector, which can result in a divsion by 0. That may mean that Pct0to10k contains zeroes.

You probably have zeros in the Pct0to10k variable.
Suppose we simulate
set.seed(123)
Pct0to10k <- runif(100, 0, 100)
Pct200korMore <- runif(100, 0, 100)
ratiohighlow <- (Pct200korMore / Pct0to10k)
TotIncidents <- rpois(100, 20)
cor(TotIncidents, ratiohighlow)
# [1] 0.03587604

Now insert a zero somewhere:
Pct0to10k[2] <- 0
ratiohighlow <- (Pct200korMore / Pct0to10k)
cor(TotIncidents, ratiohighlow)
# [1] NaN

You can identify the indices of the zero(s) with
indx <- which(is.infinite(ratiohighlow))

Telling R to only compute the correlation between complete observations will not work as the function searches for NA, not Inf.
cor(TotIncidents, ratiohighlow, use="complete.obs")
# [1] NaN

But you can omit these values when calculating the correlation:
cor(TotIncidents[-indx], ratiohighlow[-indx], use="complete.obs")
[1] 0.03582789


yes that was the problem: one zero value out of 1,474 observations, and your solution worked. Thank you!
